# Find the size of a c array in function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to write a short function which takes a pointer to an array and simply returns it's size.  So far what I have is something like this:

```
int main (void) {
   double MyArray[3] = {0, 1, 2};

   int Temp = ArraySize(MyArray);

   return 0;
}

int ArraySize(double * MyArray) {
   return sizeof(MyArray) / sizeof(*MyArray);
}
```

But this doesnt seem to be working.
Any help appreciated,
Jack

Comment: Please before answering the question, make an educated guess on how many times this question would've been asked :)

Comment: I had a quick look but nothing seemed to match my question. My Bad.

Answer (score 3):

That's impossible - the pointer simply points at the first element of the array. There's no way to extract the array size from that.

You could pass the array by reference, and infer the size as a template parameter:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t ArraySize(T (&)[N]) {return N;}
```

This will only work if you have access to the array itself (as you do in your example). If it's already decayed to a pointer, then the size information has been lost.

Comment: Great! That's done the trick, can I check that I understand how this works...When you pass the array to the function the template call figures out how long the array is and that is then accessible in the function?

Comment: @JackMedley: Exactly. The template infers both the element type and the array size from the (array) type of the function argument.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible, you need to pass length in function with array. Like,

```
int ArraySize(double * MyArray, size_t length)
```

Comment: You function's signature does not fit the OP's requirements, thus your answer is not an answer.

Comment: The first 4 words are the answer “No it is not possible”. The rest is extra. Unless you arrange to put a sentinel at the end of the array (similar to how c strings work). That also changes the interface to the function.

Comment: @richard Hmmmm I see.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want. `MyArray` in function `ArraySize` is a pointer to a `double`, not an array of `double`s. You must explicitly pass the array length along with the base address of the array.